# suppress javascript error for undefined array property

Tags: javascript, suppress

I have a form build up in javascript, which i want to use for adding users and updating users.

The form holds some input elements like below. This works when i get the user data to build up the form for updating, but for adding a new user this property does not exists in the array so the script failed and stop running correctly, as expected.

The question is, what is the shortest way to suppress this error? Something php like @$params['user_email'].

- i know about try, cache
- i know about suppressing all errors on the window object.
- type of, undefined etc.

I just looking for the shortest way to do this without adding multiple lines of code for validating each property in the params array.

```
<input name="user_email" type="text" value="'+params['user_email']+'"/>
```

Comment: what is the error exactly, and what is the code that triggers the error exactly?

Comment: You should not suppress any errors. You should handle them. In your code, I guess that is a part of javascript code which generates new objects, you may do something like: `<input name="user_email" type="text" value="'+(params['user_email'] ? params['user_email'] : "" )+'"/>`. And there is nothing like `@` in php.

Comment: better to find solution to actual problem then to find solution to supressing errors..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER suppress errors. It's a very bad habit and will give you serious headaches rather sooner than later. Always do a proper check. (like following)

```
          // if available           use it            otherwise echo empty string
value="'+(params['user_email'] ? params['user_email'] : '')+'"
```

Comment: Question is tagged javascript?

Comment: @AndrewHall doesn't matter, it's exactly the same code^^ But ty for the catch;)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, pretty straight forward and common, got that in my brains now, thanks!